# remove (* char) from the required field label in form

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I'm trying to change the label of the fields that are required in django form using labels in Meta class . 
so after writing the code using this [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) , i have a problem because the name of the field changes but the -> * character <- stays there .

Code :

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
class Meta:
    model = ...
    fields = ...
    widgets = ...

    labels = {
        'email': _('email (necessary)'),
        'username': _('name (necessary)'), # the result of this -> name(necessary)* 
    }
```

Template :

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

<h1>USERS REGISTER PAGE IS FOUND!</h1>
<br>
<hr>

<div>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today</legend>
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="border-top pt-3">
        <small class="text-muted">
            Already Have An Account ? <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'users-login' %}">Sign In</a>
        </small>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

so , how can I remove this annoying * ?

Comment: Well you use a translation. Are you sure you updated the translations (and recompiled these)?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes im sure

Comment: How are you rendering the form? The labels should not contain the asterisk, or the "required" or "necessary" labels anyway.

Comment: @AKX: good point. Alex, are you sure the asterisk is part of the label, and not inserted because the field is for example required?

Comment: @AKX i understand  . but if I want to write any other label that i want, the problem still persists

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm a little confused. How can I check?

Comment: Please add the template code you're using to render this form.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sry i didnt understand . no, I didn't enter the asterisk , it was there

Comment: Django is not adding the asterisk for you, not that I can see.

Are you sure there's no CSS `::after { content: " *"; }` sort of thing at play here?

Comment: @AKX no there is no css file , it's just a bootstrap . i tried everything, i am really confused

Comment: Bootstrap has an asterisk for required fields, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @AKX thank you problem solved. in this case, using crispy isn't recommended .

Comment: @Alex Now that you added proper context to the question, I added a proper answer. ;)

Comment: @AKX problem was so annoying . thank you

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The root cause here was apparently the `django-crispy-forms` package being used for rendering the form.

[Its documentation has a section on the "required" asterisks](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html#change-required-fields); the easiest, as linked, is to hide the asterisk field; you don't need to change the labels:

```
.asteriskField {
    display: none;
}
```